# How to talk about any objects mathematically? (In this case binary trees)

Tags: definition, foundations, data-structure

For context I was doing the following exercise in Isabelle theorem prover tutorial:

> Let datatype `'a tree = Tip "'a tree" 'a "'a tree"`
>
> 1. Define a function `set :: 'a tree => 'a set` which transforms a tree into a set
> 2. Define a function `ord :: 'a tree => bool` which checks if a tree is ordered

Now when I was doing the 2nd task, I wanted to think about it mathematically instead of just as a function in isabelle. Btw in this case a tree is ordered if for any node $x$, all the nodes in the left subtree are less than $x$ and all the nodes in the right subtree are greater than $x$. For example this tree is ordered:

```
      10
    /   \
   5     15
  / \    /  \
 2   7  12  18
```

If we look at that tree, we can flatten the tree like this:
2 5 7 10 12 15 18

I don't know what that sequence or list is called but in that sequence for any node $x$, all the elements to the left are nodes in the left subtree of $x$. For example if we take 10 in that sequence, then 2, 5 and 7 are all elements of the left subtree of the node 10.

If we think about a binary tree by taking that type of sequence above, call it $a_0, a_1, ... , a_n$ then the binary tree is ordered if $a_i < a_{i+1}$ for all $i$    (i think) The best way i can describe the tree is that we let $a_0$ be the left most node in the entire tree and then $a_1$ is the parent of that, then $a_2$ is either the right child node of the parent, or it's the parent of $a_1$ ... (this is not a very good description)

Thinking about the problem like that is way more fun than just trying to implement the function `ord :: 'a tree => bool` in a certain programming language, but the issue here is that this explanation above is definitely not a valid explanation mathematically. How would the sequence $a_0,a_1, ... , a_n$ actually be defined? Can I define it myself or does it have to be like standard or something?

If I want to talk about any objects kind of mathematically like this, how can I do it? It's ok to talk about this problem with the sequence $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ if I can actually define it properly right?

Comment: This "flattened list" is usually called the *in-order traversal* of the tree, which you may like to search for on the Internet. You shouldn't worry so much about if it's "OK" to talk about something :-) mathematicians aren't the police! I think the way you've explained it, together with the example you've given make it perfectly clear what you're talking about. Sure, you could be more formal, but it is very situational as to whether that's necessary. Now if you want to write a program it will be helpful to have a definition that you can turn into an algorithm, which the answer below gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define such *flatten* function $f$ from a binary tree to a sequence, one way is to define

- $f$ of empty tree be the empty sequence $()$, and
- $f$ of a tree with root value $x$, left subtree $L$ and right subtree $R$ be (recursively) $$f(L) \oplus (x) \oplus f(R),$$ where $\oplus$ denotes sequence concatenation.

This is similar to how one may define such function in a program.